# Kendo Tab Strip

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-tabstrip

What are the methods which are available to Add tabs to the Tab strip dynamically?
I have already tried adding the Tab while dynamically creating the Tab strip on the fly but not able to load the content inside it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Your question would appear to be answerable by [reading the documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/TabStripBuilder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo basically provides three function to add the Tabs.
1. Insert Before (which will add the Tab before the 1st Tab)
2. Insert After (Which adds the tab after the 1st Tab)
3. Append (Which adds the Tab to already existing Tab Strip

In your case you need to go with the either first or second approach as you are dynamically creating the Tab.

One suggestion:
As Kendo insert Tab after 1st and not after the Selected Tab which is not a normal scenario, you can use select function before adding a Tab